# Flutter realtime database: .childOrderBy() not defined

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I'm trying to listen & query to the realtime database in flutter.

```
 StreamSubscription<Event> _messagesSubscription;
      DatabaseReference _messagesRef =
          FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('messages');

      realTimeDataBaseListen() {
        _messagesSubscription = _messagesRef
            .childOrderBy("Group_id")
            .equalTo("abc123")
            .onChildChanged
            .listen((Event event) {
          print('Child CHANGED: ${event.snapshot.value}');
        }, onError: (Object o) {
          final DatabaseError error = o;
          print('Error: ${error.code} ${error.message}');
        });
      }
```

But I get the error:

```
childOrderBy() not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `orderByChild`:

```
.orderByChild("Group_id")
            .equalTo("abc123")
            .onChildChanged
            .listen((Event event) {
```

Check the following :

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/lib/src/query.dart#L165